# Programmatically Remove Font Smoothing

Tags: macos, fonts, antialiasing

Is there a way to programmatically turn off font smoothing/antialiasing on OS X?

Comment: @VladLazarenko please be nice in comments. thanks

Comment: @CharlesB: Wasn't it nice? :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best done through applescript using the appearance suite